# Text files uploaded to S3 are encoded strangely?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encoding

This is the strangest error, and I don't even know where to start understanding what's wrong.

S3 has been working well, up until suddenly one day (yesterday) it strangely encodes any text file uploaded to strange characters. Whenever a text file has Å, Ä, Ö or any other UTF-8 comparable but none English characters, the text file is messed up. I've tried uploading using various clients, as well as the web interface of AWS. The upload goes well, then I download the file and it's messed up. I've tried downloading it to my Mac, I've tried downloading it onto a Raspberry with Linux on it. Same error.

Is there any encoding done by Amazons S3 servers?!

Comment: Yep, that worked for me. Using the s3cmd tool, I added the flags `--encoding=UTF-8 --add-encoding-exts=js,html` and it worked. Thanks @SonyKadavan

Comment: @SonyKadavan Could you post your answer, Others could find it helpfull. Like this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/41623185/3664960

Answer (score 34):

I had the same problem and I solved it by adding `charset=utf-8` in **properties -> metadata** of the file

[image]

Comment: There is no metadata part in my s3Bucket :( When does it change?

Comment: Maybe you need add it from the button "+ Add Metadata" @albatross

Answer (score 14):

You can explicitly set the "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8", on the file in the S3 console.

This will tell S3 to serve as text.

Comment: Where exactly should we set this?

Comment: In my case using the aws-sdk-ruby library, I did: `bucket.object("myfile.txt").put(body: "unicöde cöntänt", content_type: "text/plain; charset=utf-8")`

Comment: in case of CSV it converts into binary/octate format, anyone know fix?
`"text/csv; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: @pootzko select file/folder > actions > change metadata

Comment: @ManojJadhav any solution for csv files?

Answer (score 7):

For those who are using boto3 (python 3) to upload and are having strange characters instead of accentuation (such as in portuguese and french languages, for example), [Toni Chaz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48664153/2120931)'s and [Sony Kadavan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41842266/2120931)'s answers gave me the hint to fix. Adding ";charset=utf-8" to ContentType argument when calling put_object was enough to the accentuation be shown correctly.

```
content_type="text/plain;charset=utf-8"
bucket_obj.put_object(Key=key, Body=data, ContentType=content_type)
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding `<meta charset="utf-8" />` in the `<head>` of the .html files fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why, but the answer from Sony Kadavan didn't work in my case.

Rather than:

> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

I used:

> Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Which seemed to work.

Comment: in my case it also didn't helped, but the setting up the encoding during reading the file from the filesystem has helped for me

Answer (score 1):

In my problem I got the problem with reading file form the filesystem as UFT8 too,, so I got the wrong file encoding in s3 until I have added

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, "UTF8");
```

instead of

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream);
```

please note of this possible problem too

Answer (score -8):

If your data includes `non-ASCII multibyte characters (such as Chinese or Cyrillic characters)`, you must load the data to `VARCHAR` columns. The `VARCHAR` data type supports four-byte UTF-8 characters, but the `CHAR` data type only accepts single-byte ASCII characters.

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_loading_unicode_data.html

Comment: redshift is not s3