# AWS Datapipeline - issue with accented characters

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-data-pipeline

I am new to AWS datapipeline. I created a successful datapipeline to pull all the content from RDS to S3 bucket. Everything works. I see my .csv file in S3 bucket. But I am storing spanish names in my table, in csv I see "Garcï¿½a" instead of "García"

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the wrong codepage is used. Just reference the correct codepage and you should be fine. The following topic might help: [Text files uploaded to S3 are encoded strangely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403071/text-files-uploaded-to-s3-are-encoded-strangely)

Comment: S3 files are dynamically generated. I need a solution to fix it in datapipeline.

Comment: Is the pipeline-transfer changing your data? That would make no sense however i could be wrong.
Your Data is misinterpreted by either your Export or Import process thorugh usage of a wrong codepage ( for your needs).

Comment: My data is fine. My apis are working fine and serving website fine. I am trying to get downloadable csv which is giving me trouble. S3 is not an issue either.

Answer (score 1):

AWS DataPipeline is implemented in Java, and uses [JDBC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdbc/index.html) (Java Database Connectivity) drivers (specifically, [MySQL Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/) for MySQL in your case) to connect to the database. According to the [Using Character Sets and Unicode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html) section of the documentation, the character set used by the connector is automatically determined based on the [`character_set_server`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_server) system variable on the RDS/MySQL server, which is set to `latin1` by default.

If this setting is not correct for your application (run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character%';` in a MySQL client to confirm), you have two options to correct this:

1. Set `character_set_server` to `utf8` on your RDS/MySQL server. To make this change permanently from the RDS console, see [Modifying Parameters in a DB Parameter Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html#USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.Modifying) for instructions.
2. Pass additional JDBC properties in your DataPipeline configuration to override the character set used by the JDBC connection. For this approach, add the following JDBC properties to your [`RdsDatabase`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-rdsdatabase.html) or [`JdbcDatabase`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-jdbcdatabase.html) object (see [properties reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)):

   `"jdbcProperties": "useUnicode=true,characterEncoding=UTF-8"`

Comment: I'm not 100% confident about the syntax for passing multiple properties to `jdbcProperties`- the documentation only says "Pairs of the form A=B that will be set as properties on jdbc connections for this database". It might instead be `useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8` or something else entirely. Let me know if either form works if you try this option.

Comment: You are right. It gave me an error - The connection property 'allowMultiQueries' only accepts values of the form: 'true', 'false', 'yes' or 'no'. The value 'true,useUnicode=true,characterEncoding=UTF-8' is not in this set.

Comment: and is not correct either. The connection property 'allowMultiQueries' only accepts values of the form: 'true', 'false', 'yes' or 'no'. The value 'true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8' is not in this set.

Comment: OK, here's two more syntax ideas to try: 1. Multiple `jdbcProperties` keys, one for each property you wish to set: `"jdbcProperties": "useUnicode=true", "jdbcProperties": "characterEncoding=UTF-8"`; 2. Pass an array to `jdbcProperties`: `"jdbcProperties": ["useUnicode=true", "characterEncoding=UTF-8"]`. Let me know if either works.

Comment: added as per your instructions. No errors. Thank you. But...the result is same "Gonzï¿½lez" :(

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little similar to this [Text files uploaded to S3 are encoded strangely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403071/text-files-uploaded-to-s3-are-encoded-strangely/41783310#41783310). If so, kindly reference my answer there.