# How to set the charset on a recursive AWS upload with aws s3 cp?

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-s3, character-encoding, amazon-cloudfront

I'm uploading a large directory of files to S3 which I know to all be UTF-8 encoded.  However when these are rendered in a browser via cloudfront some characters are getting scrambled because the browser isn't informed of the charset.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48664153) that this can be fixed by simply setting the charset in the content-type metadata.  (eg: `text/plain; charset=utf-8`).

The problem is that I need to do this for a lot of files inside a CI pipeline and I can't even garantee all files will be the same content-type.

What I'm hoping is that the `aws s3 cp` command has some way to deal with this, since it's automatically attaching the content type metadata.

Comment: Are you currently using the `--content-type` command line option?

Comment: @jarmod no, as stated, the content-type is not the same for all files in the directory so it's hard to see how I could use that.

Comment: Long standing issue: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1346

Answer (score 0):

It's the client's responsibility to set an appropriate content type when uploading to S3.

The awscli guesses the mime type of each file to be uploaded and sends an appropriate content-type. If that doesn't work for you on certain files then you need to decide, in advance ideally, how to identify those files, determine an appropriate content-type for each one individually, and override the awscli's default inference by supplying an appropriate `--content-type` parameter on each upload.

I don't believe that awscli will populate a charset so you might need to [calculate the mime type yourself](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/file-mime-types) (unless you know in advance e.g. by file extension or from some other local metadata) and append the charset to the supplied mime type, for example. `--content-type "text/html; charset=utf-8"`.

Comment: You're saying there's no way to inform aws cli of this detail?

Comment: If I understand your question, that's exactly the opposite of what I'm saying. I will re-read and clarify as needed. Yes, you can override the awscli's mime type inference, and you supply the `--content-type xyz` command line parameter to do that (on each call to `aws s3 cp` for each object). But that seems obvious, so perhaps I misunderstand your question.

Comment: no I meant the detail of [just] the charset. I realise they get munged into the same thing (content-type).  But I can't easily specify every mime-type without building my own inference engine.  I just want to patch in the charset.

Comment: If you want to avoid the mime type detection and rely on awscli then I'm not sure you can do this. One option would be to 'update' the content-type post-upload to append `; charset=utf-8` to the content-type metadata (and unfortunately you can't simply update the metadata itself alone; you have to do an S3 copy to self with modified metadata afaik).